# ubuntu server minimal and openbox

Tags: openbox

I installed Ubuntu Debian 23.10 server version. I also installed Openbox + PCManFM-Qt + VirtualBox Guest Additions because I am on a VirtualBox virtual machine. After the reboot, it asked me if I wanted LXQt or Openbox. I chose Openbox, but it redirected me to LXQt, and the icons and the mouse cursor are not visible. When I try to launch the terminal, it tells me that the type of terminal I'm trying to launch does not exist. Do any of you have an idea of what could be the issue? Thanks to everyone.

Comment: What is Ubuntu Debian? Is it like Lion Leopard?

Comment: It's helpful if you're specific as to what exactly (packages/commands) you installed; you installed `pcmanfm-qt` thus did install the core part of LXQt (`pcmanfm-qt` runs the background/display of the desktop & also acts as file-manager) which is why LXQt session appears, but you did **not** install all of LXQt it appears; and the WM `openbox` (LXQt is WM agnostic so you can use whichever you like). You mention launch terminal, but haven't said what terminal you installed as you didn't mention installing any (`openbox` is a WM, you only installed part of LXQt & not `qterminal` for example)

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are completely separate systems.  They are only related in that Ubuntu derives from Debian a large portion of the packages.  However, they are *NOT* the same OS at their base.  Are you using Ubuntu, or Debian?

Comment: but not exist a mode  for have openbox without any other part ?  example  if  i want  somthing for browse file i must install pcmanfm-qt  but  this require install LXQT , but is not possible have a  somthing that can browse  file  without installa LXQT  but install only a light  packet?

Comment: `openbox` is a window manager, it'll handle windows but doesn't actually have a menu of any sort (though `obmenu` is an optional menu for it; one of its addons). `pcmanfm-qt` can be used only as file-manager, but it's an integral part of LXQt just as `pcmanfm` was an integral part of LXDE; they're dual purpose file-manager & desktop handlers. You've not said what packages you actually installed, any other components as you only mention `openbox` & no ob-extensions, & the LXQt file-manager/desktop app but no terminal (eg. LXQt uses `qterminal` as it's terminal for example).