# ubuntu server rre-try to install again

Tags: 23.10

I've recently installed the following tools on Ubuntu Server version 23.10:

```
OPENBOX
XFE
QTERMINAL
TINT2
LXAppearance
Nitrogen
LIGHTDM
XINIT
```

After restarting, LightDM prompts me for login. I enter my password, but it doesn't allow me to proceed. Any suggestions or insights on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention a number of packages from different GUI/UIs, ie. LXAppearance  is for the LXDE (GTK2) desktop, Qterminal is for a Qt5 desktop like LXQt, XFE being different again...  Have you setup any sessions for your wanted GUI for LightDM to operate with, as you've picked packages from different environment/desktops.

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497685/ubuntu-server-minimal-and-openbox   *Packages that had been installed was requested & never provided in that question*

Comment: You probably need a session manager. In LXDE it was lxsession. But why go about this in such a chaotic way? Just install a desktop.